# How to re-populate a form from another controller if it contains errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am studying the get start with rails guide, and add error validation on comments but if I have errors, the form is not re-populated.

I post dates from `/car/show.html.erb`

I check errors with flash (works correctly) but my form become empty if error.

Below code of my `comments_controller.rb` controller :

```
def create
 @car = Car.find(params[:car_id])
  if @comment = @car.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:email,:sujet,:commentaire))
    flash[:error] = @comment.errors
    flash.keep[:error]
    render 'car/show'
  else
    redirect_to car_path(@car)
 end
end
```

Below cars/show.html.erb

```
<h1>Fiche détaillée</h1>

<%= @car.marque %><br>
<%= @car.modele %><br>
<%= @car.nbkm %><br>
<%= @car.couleur %><br>
<%= @car.disponibilite %><br>
<hr>
<h1><%= pluralize(@car.comments.count,'Commentaire') %></h1>
<% @car.comments.each do |k| %>
<%= k.email %><br>
<%= k.sujet %><br>
<%= k.commentaire %><br>
<hr>
<% end %>
<hr>
<h1>Ajouter votre commentaire</h1>
<div style='width:300px;'>

<% flash.each do |key, msg| %>
<p class="bg-danger" style='padding:10px;'><%= pluralize(msg.count,'error') %></p>
  <ul><% msg.full_messages.each do |m|%>
        <li><%= m %></li>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
</ul>


<%= form_for ([@car,@car.comments.build]) do |co| %>

      <%= co.label :'Email' %><br>
      <%= co.text_field :email , class: 'form-control' %><br>
  <br>

      <%= co.label :'Sujet' %><br>
  <%= co.text_field :sujet , class: 'form-control'%><br>
  <br>

      <%= co.label :'Commentaire' %><br>
  <%= co.text_area :commentaire , class: 'form-control' %><br>
  <br>

      <%= co.submit :'Envoyer votre commentaire', class: 'btn btn-info'%>

<% end %>
```

I don't know how to deal with render when controller is not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
**Edit:**

```
def create
 @comment = Comment.new(params[:comment].permit(:email,:sujet,:commentaire))
  if !@comments.save
    flash[:error] = @comment.errors
    flash.keep[:error]
    render 'car/show'
  else
    redirect_to car_path(@car)
end
end
```

car/show method:

```
def show
@car = Car.find(params[:id])
@comment = @car.comments.build
end
```

Change

```
<%= form_for ([@car,@car.comments.build]) do |co| %>
```

To

```
<%= form_for @comment do |co| %>
```

Comment: Ok, Assuming that you are using @comment in form. Move that declaration to `car/show` method like `@comment = Comment.new` or `@comment = @car.build_comment`

Comment: **Repopulate works thank you** but know i meet another issue, if i submit form and have errors, datas are displayed above the form. I update my **cars/show.html.erb form in my question** to see all my code maybe i made again something wrong !!

Comment: Edited all my answer. Try to understand